# Python doesn't use decimal point separator in 'Region and language'

Tags: python, system-settings, internationalization, gettext

If I open the 'Region and language' dialog, I have 'Formats' set to 'Germany'. If I click that setting, the 'Numbers' preview is '123.456.789,00' (comma as a decimal separator).

But if I run `python3 -c 'import locale; print(locale.localeconv()["decimal_point"])'`, it outputs `.` (a dot, not a comma).

How can I get the decimal point as configured by the user in the 'Region and language' dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `locale.setlocale()` too.

```
python3 -c 'import locale; locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ""); print(locale.localeconv()["decimal_point"])'
```

Comment: This simply adopts whatever is in `LC_ALL`. On my system, somehow all the variables reported by `locale` are not de_DE even though Germany is selected as mentioned.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: No, it imports all the locale categories which are currently effective (i.e. in accordance with the output of the `locale` command). If you switched to German as Format in the current session, you need to relogin to have the `LC_NUMERIC` variable (which affects the decimal separator) updated.